How to restore USB 10/100/1000 Network Interface after deleting it?
I deleted the USB 10/100/1000 network interface service and clicked no when asked if I'd like to have it returned on next connection. How can it be restored or all network settings reset?
This previous question's terminal commands answers do not work on macOS Sonoma 14.4.1 on a MacBook Pro 14" Nov 2023 (M3 Pro version) and Dell WD19DCS dock.

Screenshot below shows the Add Service dialogue window which does not list USB LAN option.


What type of Mac hardware are you? I’ve never had to restart to be able to add a new network interface, but that would be a nice step to try and then edit more details in the body of the post. If you have a USB dongle, model there might be relevant as how it’s connected.

Open a shell and try: sudo networksetup -detectnewhardware (you'll then need to enter the password of an administrator account).

Make sure you have a live Ethernet cable connected!

Yes, I ran that command and there is no output in terminal. Does that mean it has run with no comments/nothing to report?
Ethernet cable connection is through the Dell dock and USB-C

Yes, that command won't produce any output at all - and you'll need to quit and re-open System Settings (Preferences) > Network to see if it produced any change.

I'm not sure if restarting or this command or both fixed it but it's back. Thank you!
